# How do you do your test development from home?

Tags: 2010, 2007, development

Assuming you don't have a Windows Server machine available from home what do you do to test your deployments? Do you just compile once you're back in the office and have a test box available or do you do all of your work in a virtual machine with Windows Server installed on it? Surely there's something that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At my work and so should most if not all have a VM(virtual Machine) with sharepoint, k2(optional), SQL server, VS2008 -vs2010 and anything else that you would need.

From the VPC you can do what you like as its your dev place and if you break it then its your fault ;) otherwise you can develop anything you like and test it on the VPC, You can hav this on a laptop or anywhere and develop on it as its all local on the VPC.

When all goes well on the VPC you would then have to send it to the DEV server for testing. It mimmics the Int or live server. Here you would test the app to make sure no bugs or anything else is going wrong and if it is, its not the end of the world as its a dev box just for developers. The DEV server also has the SQL database and most thing on it aswell.

The next stage is Int server, where maybe its a mirror copy of Live server and where your company would use internally. Here is the final releas just befor live. This part you give it to an independant tester or have it used by the company as a trial before it goes out live, or both. On the Int server this is where front end (hive files) and SQL server are seperate from each other.. we also have a K2 server.

From there your support team should semd it out to the live servers for your clients

The VPC I use is Oracle VM VirtualBox. I would recommend you set it up and then save a copy of the VHD (virtual hard disk) just incase anything goes wrong

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I used local virtual machines (running in VirtualBox) for years but now I use CloudShare (http://cloudshare.com/) for most of my SharePoint development and testing (no, I do not work for CloudShare). CloudShare provides you with different virtual machine "templates" which you can use for SharePoint development/testing purposes and they also give you several different methods for sharing and copying files from these virtual machines to your workstation and back. You can sign up for their free trial (14 days) first to see if it will help with your needs of working between your home and office.

Answer (score -1):

Use Remote Desktop Connection to connect to your work environment.

Comment: I work in large scale finance and given the databases I work with they're not going to open this up :(

Comment: That way you should not program from home cause you can break NDA - if your source code is stolen from your home pc :)